# Batch normalization code optimization?

Tags: python, performance, memory-optimization, pytorch

I am trying to implement [Deep Quaternion Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.04604). I was able to implement the batch normalization technique. But it requires a lot of GPU memory. Is there any way I can optimize the code provided below?

```py
 class MyQuaternionBatchNorm2d(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features, eps=1e-5, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True):
        super(MyQuaternionBatchNorm2d, self).__init__()
        self.num_features = num_features
        self.qnum_features = num_features//4
        self.eps = eps
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.affine = affine
        self.track_running_stats = track_running_stats
        
        if self.affine:
            self.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(self.qnum_features, 10))
            self.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(num_features))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('weight', None)
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)
            
        if self.track_running_stats:
            self.register_buffer('running_mean', torch.zeros(self.qnum_features,4))
            self.register_buffer('running_covar', torch.zeros(self.qnum_features,10))
            self.running_covar[:,0] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.running_covar[:,1] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.running_covar[:,2] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.running_covar[:,3] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.register_buffer('num_batches_tracked', torch.tensor(0, dtype=torch.long))
        else:
            self.register_buffer('running_mean',None)
            self.register_buffer('running_covar', None)
            self.register_parameter('num_batches_tracked', None)
        self.reset_parameters()
        
    def reset_running_stats(self):
        if self.track_running_stats:
            self.running_mean.zero_()
            self.running_covar.zero_()
            self.running_covar[:,0] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.running_covar[:,1] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.running_covar[:,2] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.running_covar[:,3] = 1/ np.sqrt(4)
            self.num_batches_tracked.zero_()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        self.reset_running_stats()
        
        if self.affine:
            torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.weight)
            torch.nn.init.constant_(self.weight[:,0], 1/ np.sqrt(4))
            torch.nn.init.constant_(self.weight[:,4], 1/ np.sqrt(4))
            torch.nn.init.constant_(self.weight[:,7], 1/ np.sqrt(4))
            torch.nn.init.constant_(self.weight[:,9], 1/ np.sqrt(4))
            torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.bias)
            
    def _check_input_dim(self, input):
        if input.dim() != 4:
            raise ValueError('expected 4D input (got {}D input)'
                             .format(input.dim()))
    
    @staticmethod
    def _decomposition_v1(r,i,j,k,Vrr, Vri, Vrj, Vrk, Vii, Vij, Vik, Vjj, Vjk, Vkk):
        Wrr = torch.sqrt(Vrr)
        Wri = (1.0 / Wrr) * (Vri)
        Wii = torch.sqrt((Vii - (Wri.pow(2))))
        Wrj = (1.0 / Wrr) * (Vrj)
        Wij = (1.0 / Wii) * (Vij - (Wri*Wrj))
        Wjj = torch.sqrt((Vjj - (Wij.pow(2) + Wrj.pow(2))))
        Wrk = (1.0 / Wrr) * (Vrk)
        Wik = (1.0 / Wii) * (Vik - (Wri*Wrk))
        Wjk = (1.0 / Wjj) * (Vjk - (Wij*Wik + Wrj*Wrk))
        Wkk = torch.sqrt((Vkk - (Wjk.pow(2) + Wik.pow(2) + Wrk.pow(2))))
        
        cat_W_1 = torch.cat([Wrr, Wri, Wrj, Wrk])
        cat_W_2 = torch.cat([Wri,Wii, Wij, Wik])
        cat_W_3 = torch.cat([Wrj, Wij, Wjj, Wjk])
        cat_W_4 = torch.cat([Wrk, Wik, Wjk, Wkk])
        
        output =  cat_W_1[None,:,None,None]  *  r.repeat(1,4,1,1) + cat_W_2[None,:,None,None] *   i.repeat(1,4,1,1) \
                    + cat_W_3[None,:,None,None]  *   j.repeat(1,4,1,1) +  cat_W_4[None,:,None,None]  *  k.repeat(1,4,1,1)

        return output
    
    def forward(self, input):
        self._check_input_dim(input)
        r,i,j,k = torch.chunk(input, 4, dim=1)
        
        exponential_average_factor = 0.0

        if self.training and self.track_running_stats:
            if self.num_batches_tracked is not None:
                self.num_batches_tracked += 1
                if self.momentum is None:  # use cumulative moving average
                    exponential_average_factor = 1.0 / float(self.num_batches_tracked)
                else:  # use exponential moving average
                    exponential_average_factor = self.momentum

        # calculate running estimates
        if self.training:
            mean_r, mean_i, mean_j, mean_k = r.mean([0, 2, 3]),i.mean([0, 2, 3]),j.mean([0, 2, 3]),k.mean([0, 2, 3])
            n = input.numel() / input.size(1)
            mean = torch.stack((mean_r, mean_i, mean_j, mean_k), dim=1)
            # update running mean
            with torch.no_grad():
                self.running_mean = exponential_average_factor * mean + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_mean
                    
            r = r-mean_r[None, :, None, None]
            i = i-mean_i[None, :, None, None]
            j = j-mean_j[None, :, None, None]
            k = k-mean_k[None, :, None, None]
            
            Vrr = (r.pow(2).mean([0, 2, 3])) + self.eps
            Vii = (i.pow(2).mean([0, 2, 3])) + self.eps
            Vjj = (j.pow(2).mean([0, 2, 3])) + self.eps
            Vkk = (k.pow(2).mean([0, 2, 3])) + self.eps
            Vri = ((r*i).mean([0, 2, 3]))
            Vrj = ((r*j).mean([0, 2, 3]))
            Vrk = ((r*k).mean([0, 2, 3]))
            Vij = ((i*j).mean([0, 2, 3]))
            Vik = ((i*k).mean([0, 2, 3]))
            Vjk = ((j*k).mean([0, 2, 3])) 

            with torch.no_grad():
                self.running_covar[:,0] = exponential_average_factor * Vrr * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,0]
                self.running_covar[:,1] = exponential_average_factor * Vii * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,1]
                self.running_covar[:,2] = exponential_average_factor * Vjj * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,2]
                self.running_covar[:,3] = exponential_average_factor * Vkk * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,3]
                
                self.running_covar[:,4] = exponential_average_factor * Vri * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,4]
                self.running_covar[:,5] = exponential_average_factor * Vrj * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,5]
                self.running_covar[:,6] = exponential_average_factor * Vrk * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,6]
                self.running_covar[:,7] = exponential_average_factor * Vij * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,7]
                self.running_covar[:,8] = exponential_average_factor * Vik * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,8]
                self.running_covar[:,9] = exponential_average_factor * Vjk * n / (n - 1) + (1 - exponential_average_factor) * self.running_covar[:,9]
        else:
            mean = self.running_mean
            Vrr = self.running_covar[:,0]+self.eps
            Vii = self.running_covar[:,1]+self.eps
            Vjj = self.running_covar[:,2]+self.eps
            Vkk = self.running_covar[:,3]+self.eps
            
            Vri = self.running_covar[:,4]+self.eps
            Vrj = self.running_covar[:,5]+self.eps
            Vrk = self.running_covar[:,6]+self.eps
            Vij = self.running_covar[:,7]+self.eps
            Vik = self.running_covar[:,8]+self.eps
            Vjk = self.running_covar[:,9]+self.eps
           
            r = r-mean[None,:,0,None,None]
            i = i-mean[None,:,1,None,None]
            j = j-mean[None,:,2,None,None]
            k = k-mean[None,:,3,None,None]
            
        # standardized_output
        input = self._decomposition_v1(r,i,j,k, Vrr, Vri, Vrj, Vrk, Vii, Vij, Vik, Vjj, Vjk, Vkk)
        
        if self.affine:
            r,i,j,k = torch.chunk(input, 4, dim=1)
            
            cat_gamma_1 = torch.cat([self.weight[:,0], self.weight[:,1], self.weight[:,2], self.weight[:,3]])
            cat_gamma_2 = torch.cat([self.weight[:,1], self.weight[:,4], self.weight[:,5], self.weight[:,6]])
            cat_gamma_3 = torch.cat([self.weight[:,2], self.weight[:,5], self.weight[:,7], self.weight[:,8]])
            cat_gamma_4 = torch.cat([self.weight[:,3], self.weight[:,6], self.weight[:,8], self.weight[:,9]])


            input =  cat_gamma_1[None,:,None,None] * r.repeat(1,4,1,1) \
                    + cat_gamma_2[None,:,None,None] * i.repeat(1,4,1,1) \
                    + cat_gamma_3[None,:,None,None] * j.repeat(1,4,1,1) \
                    + cat_gamma_4[None,:,None,None] * k.repeat(1,4,1,1) \
                    + self.bias[None, :, None, None]
        return input
```

I will explain the forward section. So the basic formula for batch normalization is `x* = (x - E[x]) / sqrt(var(x))`, where `x*` is the new value of a single component, `E[x]` is its mean within a batch and `var(x)` is its variance within a batch.

However, as it is quaternion batch normalization,it has 4 parts `r` which is the real part and `i, j, and k`, are the imaginary part.

The equation extends to `x* = W(x - E[x]) / (var(x))`. `W` is one of the matrices from the Cholesky decomposition of `V^-1` where `V` is the variance.In the code,`E[x]` is computed using the `mean` variable. V is computed in `Vxy` and `V^-1` i.e. `W` is computed in the `_decomposition_v1` function. This is applied to the input.

Finally, that formula further extends to `x** = gamma * x* + beta`, where `x**` is the final normalized value. `gamma` i.e. `cat_gamma_x` and `beta` i.e. `self.beta` are learned per layer.

Note: The num_features need to be in multiples of 4.

Thank you,
Shreyas

Comment: Please tell us more about what the code is actually supposed to accomplish. Can you summarize the goal of the code? Thank you.

Comment: I edited the question. Please take a look and let me know if you need more information. Thank you.